# Salto de linea php html

Tags: php, html, css

**El problema es que el pie de pagina o footer esta pegado a las imagenes que se van subiendo en el modulo de galería, pero el problema es que no da el salto de linea.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO DE GALERIA**

```
<!-- gallery -->
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
    <div class="w3ls-heading">
            <h3>Gallery</h3>
            <p class="sub">We know that we are your best option</p>
    </div>
```

```
 <?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT idgaleria, nombres, descripcion, imagen FROM galeria");
if($results){ 

//fetch results set as object and output HTML
$products_item="";
//../vistas/img/galeria/fish/fish.jpg18-11-18-02-11-28534.jpg
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 gallery-grid">
        <div class="wpf-demo-4">  
            <a href="{$obj->imagen}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="SPOT">  
                <img src="{$obj->imagen}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="view-caption">
                        <p>Zoom</p>
                    </div> 
            </a>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOT;
}

echo $products_item;

}
include"pie.php";

?>
```

**QUIERO QUE SE VEA DE ESTA MANERA Y EL SALTO Y DESPUES EL FOOTER:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy bien esta manera fue la que me funciono, lo que hice fue crear un bloque de espacio en blanco en un `<style>` ya que los espacios tenían predeterminado los saltos con el `css` y no directamente con `HTML` por lo cual no me funcionaba el `<br>`

Me cree esta clase, a la que llame `salto` que únicamente contenía un bloque de espacio en blamco

```
<style type="text/css">
    .salto::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    }
</style>
```

Posteriormente al momento de imprimirlos llame la clase `salto` para que diera el espacio;

```
}

echo $products_item;

}
echo'<div class="salto"></div>'; //Aquí aplico el espacio
include 'pie.php';
?>
```

***Resultado final***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***2***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

[HTML] Podrías solucionarlo sencillo con CSS, pero como no conozco tu código CSS, y solo muestras HTML y PHP, entonces, soluciónalo de forma sencilla con HTML, con la etiqueta `<br/>`, de la siguiente forma.

**TU CÓDIGO PHP DEBERÍA QUEDAR DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA**

Agregaré solo una línea de código (`echo "<br/>";`) después de terminar el ciclo while, de esa forma, todo el bloque de imágenes se verá separado del foot.

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT idgaleria, nombres, descripcion, imagen FROM galeria");
if($results){ 

//fetch results set as object and output HTML
$products_item="";
//../vistas/img/galeria/fish/fish.jpg18-11-18-02-11-28534.jpg
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 gallery-grid">
        <div class="wpf-demo-4">  
            <a href="{$obj->imagen}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="SPOT">  
                <img src="{$obj->imagen}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="view-caption">
                        <p>Zoom</p>
                    </div> 
            </a>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOT;
}
echo $products_item;
echo "<br/>"; // puedes agregarle varios, si quieres, según creas conveniente


}
include"pie.php";

?>
```

Por si quieres profundizar tu conocimiento en la etiqueta, te dejo la documentación oficial: [Etiqueta BR](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br)

Comment: No funciona en este caso, tiene que ver con la etiqueta Style, ya que de ahí se crearon los espacios en blanco